# Accepting Answers

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answers

I'm getting the sense that we have trouble accepting answers to questions. I don't know if this is because many of the questions asked are asking for general input to a question rather than a specific answer, or if people are just forgetting.

If it's the former, I think this is a good thing--up votes work well enough to sort which responses are good and bad without needing a specific answer.

However if it's the latter and we're forgetting, this might be something to watch our for.

Comment: @Geoff, do we really need a tag called *accepted-answers*? Is there a specific purpose?

Comment: @Cyclops Sean made that tag. Geoff just went through fixing the doubles.

Comment: Wups, sorry @Geoff. Guess I should have read the history more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the types of questions we're asking are really the domain of community wikis, i.e. list of tips or resources.  Either that, or it's a subjective discussion (i.e. the "is the STL appropriate for games" question).

If there is no single right answer for a question, then the question author probably won't "accept" a single one.