# Am I not able to accept the answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm new to Unreal, and as expected I'm having a lot of difficulties.

I asked a question on the site and I received two answers, of which I understood little, or almost nothing, to be honest.

My question in question => [How do one NPC follow a succession of target points?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171819/how-do-one-npc-follow-a-succession-of-target-points/171890?noredirect=1#comment305091_171890)

That's where my dilemma comes in.

I think that if a person X tries to teach something to a person Y, and person Y does not understand, **both are guilty**.

*I am to blame, and I think in this case, I am very guilty of not having understood.*

What was written in the answers made sense to me, but that did not give me an idea of ​​what I needed to do exactly to solve my problem.

**But I think if I knew a little more about the Unreal, if I was not so new, those answers would be more than enough.**

Of course it must be very annoying for those who will respond, create a project and program everything just to answer an issue, when the error may be minimal, lack of logic, a wrong function ... But I would love to have received parts of a blueprint (this was compensated by comments from users who answered the question). On the other hand, I felt great watching my own evolution.

Now that I know how to do what I wanted, **I plan to post an answer to my own question and accept it**.

Now I'm going to post an answer that someone as ignorant as I was was, understand and know perfectly well what to do. I intend to make the answer, that if I had received it, I would know exactly what to do.

I have already scored the two answers I received as useful, it helped me get to where I am (together with the comments), and if that is not useful, **I do not know what it would be**.

**Other good questions have to do with the subject of this question:**

[A good answer exists but is not accepted](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/a-good-answer-exists-but-is-not-accepted)

[Accepting Answers](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/accepting-answers)

I also thought to edit the best of the questions (in my opinion, the one that helped me the most) and accept it.

Give me your opinion, do you think what I'm going to do is right? Do you have any suggestions?

*Sorry for any typing errors. I'm not English speaker.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-answering a question is fine.

The answer you mark as “accepted” is the one that most/best helped *you* solve your problem. If no existing answer adequately covers what *you* found to solve your problem, then by all means, post an answer that does and accept it.